# MSDeploy Auto Generated deploy.cmd path issue?

Tags: batch-file, path, msdeploy

I've been working on trying to figure out why our auto-generated `deploy.cmd`scripts will not work when installed to `C:\Program Files (x86)\OurProgram`. I finally narrowed down the issue to the closing parenthesis in `(x86)` as the script would terminate with `"Files was unexpected at this time"`. One possible solution was to manually create another batch file to set `_DeploySetParametersFile` to a Windows path ( `C:\Program^ Files^ (x86^)\OurProgram\Program.Parameters.xml`). This isn't a valid solution for me, so I dug into the auto generated file and found the issue to be 2 variables:

`RootPath 
_DeploySetParametersFile`

Both of which were referenced using `%`'s(i.e. `%RootPath%`), however as soon as they were changed to `!`'s(i.e. `!RootPath!`), no 2nd script was needed and I can run the cmd script from `Program Files (x86)` just fine. The issue of course with this is, the `deploy.cmd` file is auto-generated on each build, thus I have to change it for each build I do. My question is this: Is there a way to edit the template Visual Studio uses to generate the `deploy.cmd` file? If so, where? It seems so ridiculous that  Microsoft would have this be an issue in their web deployment.

Comment: Doublequote the file path strings.

Comment: I did, but it still tried to parse the `)` as a function. This is because the deploy.cmd script sets the variables to the directory of itself but doesn't allow for `)`. Hence why encapsulating the command file path in quotes doesn't work.

Comment: If you have actually used, `"C:\Program Files (x86)\OurProgram"` or `"%Program Files(x86)%\OurProgram"` then you should actually provide the script code and passed strings you have used, _we cannot guess!_